# Custom Audit Logs from Applications

Tags: software-recommendation, security, log

I am trying to programmatically generate custom audit logs from the applications I've written (C/C++), but currently cannot find the library/functions that would allow me to do so. I am aware of auditd and audit.rules, but what I want is the ability to generate the audits only for specific actions the application does (e.g. Only log whenever the application calculates the size of a directory and log nothing else). When I was developing on MacOS, there was a library libbsm.h which had functions such as au_open(), au_write(), and au_close() that could be called to generate a custom audit log. Is there a library available that serve as the equivalent of these libbsm functions? Or is there simply not any? Any response is appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Due to company confidentiality, I cannot share any code. I am also not using any of the default LSMs (SMACK, AppArmor, SELinux, etc.).

Comment: Hello. You are having a programming issue nothing to do with the Ubuntu OS. Question may be better off on https://stackoverflow.com/ the programming site.

Comment: @David This question is a software recommendation question, not a programming question and it would be off topic as not about programming at Stack Overflow because it is a software recommendation question which is maybe why Rice asked it here.

Answer (score 0):

The `audit` command which commits a BSM audit record to an audit log is provided by the *freebsd-manpages* package in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.

From the results of `man audit` :

NAME

```
audit — commit BSM audit record to audit log
```

SYNOPSIS

```
#include <bsm/audit.h>

int
audit(const char *record, u_int length);
```

DESCRIPTION

```
The audit() system call submits a completed BSM audit record to the system audit    
log.  

The record argument is a pointer to the specific event to be recorded and length      
is the size in bytes of the data to be written.
```

RETURN VALUES

```
Upon successful completion, the value 0 is returned; otherwise the value -1   
is returned and the global variable errno is set to indicate the error.
```